# Calendar get date and check difference two date

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I used the `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE)` to get current date. 
 So the output is today (2018/05/14).
I change the device time to `2018/06/17`. So I use the `Calendar` get the date. I got the `17`.
My question is I want to get `05/15` `05/16` .... `06/01` ... `0616` these two days. I need to know all the difference days.
So I don't know which function can do this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime

Comment: The `Calendar` class is long outdated. For your requirements the `LocalDate` class of `java.time` will serve you much better. And `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is also generally much nicer to work with (speaking from experience).

Comment: My project api level is too low. So I cannot use `LocalDate`. I don't want to update my api level

Comment: @ManLokWong For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects. This has been addressed hundreds of time on Stack Overflow. Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Certainly you can use `java.time` on low API level Android. As Basil Bourque said, add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project. See more in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). I am told the dependencies are: `compile group: 'org.threeten', name: 'threetenbp', version: '1.3.3', classifier: 'no-tzdb'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static long daysBetween(Date one, Date two) {
        long difference =  (one.getTime()-two.getTime())/86400000;
        return Math.abs(difference);
    }
```

Comment: Which question are you answering? Asking because I can’t see this as an answer to the question as asked.